# Problem cutting object - results in polygon

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

[Translated]: I can't cut the object normally, instead I have a polygon. How can I fix this so that it no longer exists?

[image: 1]

Comment: select vertex and press `x` > dissolve

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that particular face already has more than 4 verts before you attempt the cut. Blender prefers quad-based toplogy, so loop cuts don't work as expected on n-gon's (faces with more than 4 verts. Make sure the face you're trying to cut has only 4 verts

Start by joining these two vertices (Select and press <kbd>J</kbd>):

[image: Join1]

Then select these three edges, <kbd>Right-click</kbd> and select "Subdivide":

[image: Join2]

End result:

[image: Join3]